# r apply function to calculate proportions by row in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, row, apply

I'm using apply function to calculate migration transition probabilities from eight states at time t1 to the same eight states at time t2. My data is save in matrix format and named tmp (as follows). the states at time t1 are my rows, and the states at time t2 are my columns. e.g. 228 persons stayed at state 1 between t1 and t2; 3 persons moved from state 2 to state 1 between t1 and t2.

```
> class(tmp)
"matrix"

> tmp

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]

[1,]  228    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

[2,]    3   92    0    0    0    0    0    0

[3,]    0    0   30    0    0    0    0    0

[4,]    0    0    0   20    0    0    0    0

[5,]    0    0    0    0   19    0    0    0

[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

[7,]    0    0    0    3    0    0    0    0

[8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3
```

I used the follow code to calculate the probabilities of moving to or staying in a certain state. It is the proportions for cells in each row. The results are saved in tmp1.

```
> tmp1=apply(tmp,1,function(X){if (sum(X)!=0) {X/sum(X)} else {numeric(length(X))}})
```

The problem is: I expected tmp1[4,7] to be 0 (because tmp[4,7] is 0), but the code returns me 1 (bolded). Is there a problem in my apply function?

```
> tmp1

[,1]       [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]

[1,]    1 0.03157895    0    0    0    0    0    0

[2,]    0 0.96842105    0    0    0    0    0    0

[3,]    0 0.00000000    1    0    0    0    0    0

[4,]    0 0.00000000    0    1    0    0  **1**  0

[5,]    0 0.00000000    0    0    1    0    0    0

[6,]    0 0.00000000    0    0    0    0    0    0

[7,]    0 0.00000000    0    0    0    0    0    0

[8,]    0 0.00000000    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: The output is transposed from what you are likely expecting.  What you want is `t(tmp1)`

Comment: Oh I see!!! Thank you a lot!